# SVN: How to move the project from one repository to another repository

Tags: subversion

I am working on SVN. Actually I created 3 projects under the same repository.

Now I created 2 new repositories. Actually I want to move the existing two projects into these repositories.

I installed Subversion on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

Picking out individual projects in the repo needs two steps and could be difficult if you have a strange repo structure. If you are just moving all the projects into another repo then I would do this:

```
svnadmin dump path/to/oldrepo > myrepos.dump
```

You then load then into the new repo with:

```
svnadmin load path/to/newrepo < myrepos.dump
```

If you do want to pick out the individual repos then `svndumpfilter` can be used on the resultant `myrepos.dump` file:

```
cat myrepos.dump |svndumpfilter include name_of_project > name_of_project.dump
```

You then load the individual project dumps like listed above with the `svnadmin load` command.

If you don't want history then the easiest is to just use `svn export` to pull the projects you want then `svn add` them the new repository.